# Dentro do Visual Studio 2015 como reverter/desfazer um commit no Git?

Tags: git, visual-studio

Eu tenho um commit feito por um desenvolvedor no repositório remoto Git hospedado no VSTS que precisa ser revertido. A partir do Visual Studio, sem ir para prompt de comandos como reverto o commit?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Para a versão no idioma inglês:

Team Explore > Branchs > Botão direito na Branch > View History

Vai aparecer uma lista com os commits, clicando com o botão direito em algum você tem a opção de Revert.

Answer (score 1):

Se o código já está no repositório no VSTS, você vai precisar:

- Reverter o commit localmente
- Fazer `push -force`

Não é possível reverter commit em um repositório diretamente no VSTS, por isso os dois passos. O que aliás é uma característica mais do Git do que do VSTS.

No Git você interage sempre com o seu repositório e manda para o Server. O Git é um [DVCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_version_control), não um CVCS, as mudanças são sempre locais e replicadas para os repositórios, a não ser que você se conecte por SSH para um servidor Git, o que não é suportado no VSTS.